# getent passw username returns nothing on boot

Tags: ubuntu, service, startup

I wrote a script as Ubuntu startup service (that located at /etc/init.d and run at startup)
There is a line

```
HOMEDIR=`getent passwd username1 | cut -d: -f6`
```

The problem is, when I run the script in shell, being logged as *username1* or even root, the command returns

```
/home/username1
```

When the script is run on boot, the command returns nothing.
Why that happens? Maybe, the user (or super one) does not have access to the */usr/bin/passwd* file?

**UPDATE**:
The problem is *username1* is stored in remote server, so LDAP loads it while boot. When the command, referred to above, executes, LDAP status is *activating (start)* but not *active (running)*. It seems to be that since   it is not started completely, so *username1* account is not loaded to the host system.

Still I failed to decide problem, now I'm trying, any help/hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem solved!**

This is a fixed script containing the line concerning the question (this script serves dropbox daemon start | stop):

```
#!/bin/sh
# dropbox service
# Replace with linux users you want to run Dropbox clients for

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: dropbox
# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named slapd
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# X-Interactive: false
# Short-Description: dropbox service
### END INIT INFO
sleep 10s
DROPBOX_USERS="username1"
DAEMON=.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
start() {
 echo "Starting dropbox..."
 for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
 HOMEDIR=`getent passwd $dbuser | cut -d: -f6`
 if [ -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON ]; then
 HOME="$HOMEDIR" start-stop-daemon -b -o -c $dbuser -S -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON &> /dev/null
 fi
 done
}

stop() {
 echo "Stopping dropbox..."
 for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
 HOMEDIR=`getent passwd $dbuser | cut -d: -f6`
 if [ -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON ]; then
 /sbin/start-stop-daemon -o -c $dbuser -K -u $dbuser -x $HOMEDIR/$DAEMON
 fi
 done
}

status() {
 for dbuser in $DROPBOX_USERS; do
 dbpid=`pgrep -u $dbuser dropbox`
 if [ -z $dbpid ] ; then
 echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: not running."
 else
 echo "dropboxd for USER $dbuser: running (pid $dbpid)"
 fi
 done
}

case "$1" in
 start)
 start
 ;;
 stop)
 stop
 ;;
 restart|reload|force-reload)
 stop
 start
 ;;
 status)
 status
 ;;
 *)
 echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/dropbox {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|status}"
 exit 1
 esac

exit 0
```

As I discovered, the script needs LDAP server to be started, so in the line 7 I added `slapd` after `$named` facility:

```
# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named slapd
```

where `slapd` is the service for LDAP, provided in the file `/etc/init.d/slapd`, it is decribed in line 3 (`init info` block):

```
# Provides:          slapd
```

So, after I added it, I succeeded with running dropbox at startup in 50% of cases. So I added a hack:

```
sleep 10s
```

Now it works properly.